# What's the deal with Tex Live and expl3.sty?

Tags: texlive, mac, expl3

I've installed Tex Live 2010 on a mac, and when trying to use xelatex, I get the error:

!Latex Error: File `expl3.sty' not found

What is this package, and how can I get it installed on tex live? There are no updates available, according to the Tex Live utility.

Update: I've found the 'tlmgr' utility, and done: sudo tlmgr install expl3

So far, so good. Unfortunately, I am now told I need xparse.sty. xparse.sty is not available through tlmgr ("package xparse not present in package repository").

Needless to say, I am not using xparse directly, nor am I directly using calc.sty, which is the file that was mentioned just before this error.

Further update: xparse is obtained by installing 'xpackages'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a wrapper package used by various packages which rely on some experimental pieces of the LaTeX3 project. [See here](http://ctan.org/pkg/expl3)

To install it, open a terminal and type:

`sudo tlmgr install expl3`

Oops, now seen your edit. Try:

`sudo tlmgr install xpackages`

It might be necessary to do an update your system:

`sudo tlmgr update -self -all`

Comment: Thanks for these, and sorry to edit so rapidly, creating the conversation problem above!

Comment: For the newer versions, one might need `l3kernel` and `l3packages`.

Answer (score 15):

When the name of the TeX Live package containing a given file isn't obvious, you can ask tlmgr about it:

```
$ tlmgr search --global --file xparse.sty
tlmgr: package repository /home/mpg/tl/trunk/Master
xpackages:
    texmf-dist/tex/latex/xpackages/xbase/xparse.sty
```

Then use `tlmgr install` to install the required package.